# casting an object of int to int gives a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I've been banging my head against this problem for a couple of hours, and it makes no sense to me.

I've made an asp.net mvc 3 application, I've implemented forms authentication. I have made my own custom provider where i've implemented the `GetUser(..)` method and the `ValidateUser(...)` method, the rest of the implementation throws a not implemented exception

I can supply my login information to the AccountController on the logon page and I'm greeted with a welcome username!
Great, so the login appears to work.

Now I have 3 Actions on my FooController

- Index
- FirstAction
- SecondAction

The specific implementations looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FirstAction(int param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    var userID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SecondAction(int param1, int param2, string param3)
{
    var userID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    ...
}
```

As you might have guessed, I'm calling the FirstAction and SecondAction from my `Index` View with some jQuery ajax functionality.

The following line throws a null referencce exception:

```
var userID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

The weird thing is, it is only in SecondAction a null reference is thrown, the call works fine in FirstAction.

I've tried splitting it up like this

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(); 
var providerKey = user.ProviderUserKey; 
var userID = (int)providerKey.
```

Yet it still fails casting.

The MembershipUser object that Membership.GetUser(..) returns has an integer stored in the providerUserKey and NOT a Guid as the regular membership implementation has.

Any help in any shape or form is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And in what sequence are they called?

Comment: Well... it's not an object of int of it's null.. isn't it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman the sequence you call the methods in has no effect

Comment: @gdoron ProviderUserKey is an object of the type int

Comment: If you get a nullref exception on that line, then apparently `Membership.GetUser()` returns `null`.

Comment: @HansKesting the funny thing is, if I split up the call into different variables it only fails in the cast, even when the ProviderUserKey is clearly not null in the debug inspector. I can also successfully call (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey in the imediate window, where the cast works fine.

Comment: You state you can see the variable in the immediate window during debugging.  What is the *value* you can see in the debugger, of "providerKey"?

Comment: @Moo-Juice the value 19, inspecting it with quick watch also says it is an object of the type int

Comment: @thmsn well, I gave up. I would triple check everything (computers are hardly ever wrong) and post the project somewhere, so we can debug too (not sure if this is possible through SO). Especially check for null value there, some other int-like type (ie. short) and that it's not `int?` instead of `int` - which would result in such exception at casting, but only if it would be null, not 19..

Answer (score 8):

Debug! Something is not what you think it is!

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
Debug.Assert(user != null);
var userKey = user.ProviderUserKey;
Debug.Assert(userKey != null);
var userID = (int)userKey;
```

Answer (score 3):

So apparently there is no `User` returned:

```
Membership.GetUser()
```

seems to return null. And therefore all subsequent calls will cause a `NullReferenceException`. It has nothing to do with the key being `Guid`or ìnt`.

**Check whether the user is still properly logged in** in when executing the second call.

**UPDATE**
Since you stated that you have tried splitting it up and the cast causing the issue the error has to reside in the Provider.

To naroow it down, try retrieving the value into a sperate variable before trying to cast it:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
var userIDO = user.ProviderUserKey;
var userID = (int)userIDO;
```

If the `NullReference`appears on the second line, you know there is something wrong with the provider.

Comment: I've tried splitting it up like this var user = Membership.GetUser(); var providerKey = user.ProviderUserKey; var userID = (int)providerKey. Yet it still fails

Comment: It still would as you're still either trying to call an non-existent property (because user is null) or cast a null value to a value type that doesn't allow nulls (int).

Comment: Updated the question with further troubleshooting info. In general It's best in these cases to split ALL the steps up to see where the error is actually occurring. Also you mention that the debugger shows the value just fine, but that is not always an indicator since this is not a stateless process, the debugger sometimes sees other this/not sees things than the code can since it's running in a different context

Comment: @ntziolis the exception occurs on the third line, the actual cast of (int)userIDO, the comment about the debugger perhaps showing wrong values, scares me, I like to trust my debugger :P

Comment: What's the value of `userIDO` then, while debugging?

Comment: @Arek it shows an object of the type integer, with the value 19

Comment: this seems like an environment issue, what you code wise seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Cause in the second action param2 is int, not string as in the first action and it cannot be null or empty.

Comment: How can the Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey have anything to do with the params defined in the action?

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine either your user or user key is null.  So you just need to perform the relevant checks.

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();

if (user != null)
{
    object userKey = user.ProviderUserKey;

    if (userKey != null)
    {
        // Try convert the value to an int.

        // Do whatever.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value is not null and use

```
Convert.ToInt32(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
```

instead of casting to `int`, to avoid problems with boxing / unboxing.

Comment: I tested that before I posted the question, the same exception was thrown when I did a Convert.ToInt32(providerKey), heck I even rebooted cause I thought voodoo was going on in my machine, but it behaved the same way after the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The ID of a MembershipUserobject is of typ uniqueidentifier, so try this

```
var userID = new GUID(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
```

Comment: You need to provide more details in an answer other than a line of code and say "try this".  How does this solve the OP's problem, or why is it a better option.